# How code my sitemap to point to different pages

Tags: php, sitemap

For example: http://twilight.ws/sitemap

The sitemap is pointing to multiple pages as you can see. I want to do something like this and submit it to Google Sitemap. Any idea how to work this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of sitemap is that, but if you are going to submit it to Google Sitemaps you should follow their guidelines.

Google Sitemaps Guidelines:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=75712&hl=en

If you never used XML, you can take a look at this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php